# how to set PHP_AUTH_PW in php curl

Tags: php, curl

How to set the PHP_AUTH_PW and PHP_AUTH_USER parameters in php curl.

At the server end its checking for:

if(!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
{
print "Authorization error"
}

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to check out the [CURL documentation](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for PHP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is called basic-auth, and works with most browsers including curl on command line:

```
curl --user name:password http://www.example.com
```

and in PHP you set two options on your curl connection ($curl_conn):

```
curl_setopt($curl_conn, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl_conn, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');
```

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? Have you tried the basic HTTP auth example in http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php ?

Comment: hey gt the solution by adding these 2 lines:

curl_setopt($zcurl,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($zcurl,CURLOPT_USERPWD,'username:pwd');