# php curl posting to server where script is hosted doesn't work

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use curl to post data to a script which is posted on the same server however it gives me this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>401 - Unauthorized</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>401 - Unauthorized</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

It works fine on localhost, what settings do I need to change to make it work on the server though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`401 - unauthorized` probably means there is a password protection in place for the path you are trying to upload to.

You'll need to remove the protection, or [change your script so curl sends the correct credentials.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780253/how-to-set-php-auth-pw-in-php-curl)